# Hiding and unhiding a particular element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide a particular element on my browser game.
When it reaches the point of being visible it has to stay visible.
At the moment I've tried a few approaches but none of them seem to do the last part which is keeping it visible when the number of clicks goes back under the amount needed to make it visible.

CSS:

```
upgrade3 {
  display: none;
}
```

js1(which completely doesn't work):

```
function showPerk() {

    if (clicks >= price3reached || totalupgradeperk3 > 0) { 
        do{
            document.getElementById("upgrade3").style.display =="block";
        }
        while(document.getElementById("upgrade3".style.display === 'none'));
    }
    update();
}
```

js2 (works but hides the element when going under the amount needed):

```
 if (blnhideperk = true) {
    
    if (clicks >= price3reached || totalupgradeperk3 > 0) { 
        document.getElementById("upgrade3").style.display = "block";
        blnhideperk === false;
    } // use === its something wierd about js = / == / === all do different comparisons
    else {
        document.getElementById("upgrade3").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

upgrade

Comment: What's the desired result for js2?

Comment: the same as js1 but i tried a different methode of doing it

Comment: The "if (blnhideperk = true)" is an assignment, not a condition. Could you clarify what you mean there?

Comment: Maybe I should ask another way, What do you mean by " hides the element when going under the amount needed"? Isn't that what you'd expect?

Comment: Side note: I should mention that you probably mean if (blnhideperk == true) andblnhideperk = false; 1 equal sign is assignment, 2 equal signs and 3 equal signs asks if the two are equal.

Comment: Well i expected once the the display became "block" it woulnd't go back to "none". Anyway thanks for the help and I'm still learning the = signs and everything else i'm kinda happy i found out in the end how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("upgrade3").style.display = "none";
```

Note the 1 equal sign, not 2 or 3, as those have other uses.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (blnhideperk = true){

if (clicks >= price3reached || totalupgradeperk3 > 0){ 
    document.getElementById("upgrade3").style.display = "block";
    blnhideperk === false;}}
```

and moving

```
document.getElementById("upgrade3").style.display = "block";
```

out of the loop istead of in the else statement
seemed to do the trick